# Show current connected wireless network name in a label

Tags: vb.net

Quick question - I want to simply show the network name my computer is connected to in a lable.

For example, if i'm connected to wireless network 'Network' - how do I show simply that I'm connected to this network in a label or message box?

Thanks in advance
Nathan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, 
 Go to NuGet Package Manager > Manage NuGet Packages For Solution.
 click on `Browse` and search for `managedwifi`
 Install the package (There should only be one)
 Once thats done, Follow this example I have made for you.

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports System.Text
Imports NativeWifi

Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ''THIS WILL DISPLAY THE CONNECTED WIFI'S NAME ON START UP.
    Dim wlan = New WlanClient()
    Dim connectedSsids As Collection(Of [String]) = New Collection(Of String)()

    For Each wlanInterface As WlanClient.WlanInterface In wlan.Interfaces
        Dim ssid As Wlan.Dot11Ssid = wlanInterface.CurrentConnection.wlanAssociationAttributes.dot11Ssid
        connectedSsids.Add(New [String](Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(ssid.SSID, 0, CInt(ssid.SSIDLength))))

        For Each item As String In connectedSsids
            Label1.Text = item ''CHANGE THE LABEL TO A TEXTBOX OR WHERE EVER YOU WANT TO DISPLAY YOUR CONNECTED WIFI'S NAME.
        Next
    Next
End Sub
End Class
```

If you have any issue, let me know and I will do my best to reply to you quickly. 
 Happy Coding!